# how to rbind a list of file base on a file list

Tags: r

I have a list of file name and I want to do append on each list. How should I do that?

my sample list can be build using codes:

```
lst3<- list(structure(1:11, .Label = c("pk24_1.CSV", "pk24_2.CSV", "pk4.CSV", 
"pk6_1.CSV", "pk6_2.CSV", "pk6_3.CSV", "pkc.CSV", "pkc1.CSV", 
"cy1.CSV", "cy24.CSV", "cy6.CSV"), class = "factor"), structure(1:3, .Label = c("cy1.CSV", 
"cy24.CSV", "cy6.CSV"), class = "factor"), structure(1:2, .Label = c("cont.CSV", 
"cont_1.CSV"), class = "factor"), structure(1:2, .Label = c("ds.CSV", 
"ds_1.CSV"), class = "factor"), structure(1:2, .Label = c("ie.CSV", 
"ie_1.CSV"), class = "factor"), structure(1:2, .Label = c("tegu.CSV", 
"tegu_1.CSV"), class = "factor"), structure(1:2, .Label = c("til.CSV", 
"til_1.CSV"), class = "factor"))
```

Maybe it should not be class=factor. If that is the case, how should I fix this.

The main gold is I can use a code to read lst3 and run the rbind automatically.
for example:

```
PK <- rbind("pk24_1.CSV", "pk24_2.CSV", "pk4.CSV", 
"pk6_1.CSV", "pk6_2.CSV", "pk6_3.CSV", "pkc.CSV", "pkc1.CSV", 
"cy1.CSV", "cy24.CSV", "cy6.CSV")
cy <- rbind ("cy1.CSV", "cy24.CSV", "cy6.CSV")
```

The new data name is can be anything you like:
[image]

Thanks

Comment: What are those `cy` and `PK`?  Which one is the expected output

Comment: for lst3, we have 20 file name lists, I want to build a data by rbind those data. the files are in environment. Let me update the post to better explain it.

Comment: Do you want to read the datasets from those file names and then `rbind`.  I updated the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we already have objects in the global environment

```
out <- lapply(lst3, function(x)
              do.call(rbind, mget(as.character(x), envir = .GlobalEnv)))
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
out <- map(lst3, ~ mget(as.character(.x), envir = .GlobalEnv) %>%
                  bind_rows)
```

Comment: Thanks. In this way, we can change factor to character. Then what should I do for next step. I will need to build looping code for it can build multiple file by rbind the each list.

Comment: @Stataq i updated the post.  Is that what you wanted

Comment: I am looking to rbind data set. for example "cont.CSV" and "cont_1.CSV". Those two data have same data structure .

Comment: @Stataq i guess you need to first those files.  Updated the post

Comment: Thanks for the updates. I used code to read in alrge amount of .CSV. That is why my data have funny name like XX.CSV. I don't need to read them in again as they are in the environment already as dataframe. I want to rbind them.

Comment: @Stataq Do you have objects named `XX.CSV`?  What are the names of the csv objects?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225292/discussion-between-stataq-and-akrun).